# Extracting values from Array of nested Objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects and trying to extract the objects with a matched value of the array.

`const A = [{_id: 'a', name: '1'}, {_id: 'b', name: '2'}, {_id: 'c', name: '3'}]` and `const B = ['2', '3']` So, I want to match values of Array B to the Array A and get the objects into the Array C like `const C = [{_id: 'b', name: '2'}, {_id: 'c', name: '3'}]`

```
  const C = A.forEach((list) => {
    let key = []
    if(list.includes[B]) {
    key.push(list)
     }
  })
```

I am stuck at here, how can I push those objects to the Array C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter the array.

```js
const
    arrA = [{ _id: 'a', name: '1' }, { _id: 'b', name: '2' }, { _id: 'c', name: '3' }];
    arrB = ['2', '3'];
    arrC = arrA.filter(({ name }) => arrB.includes(name));

console.log(arrC);
```

Answer (score 1):

when you say matched value, it seems as if you're trying too match the name value..
if that's the case- this shoould work..

```
const A = [{_id: 'a', name: '1'}, 
           {_id: 'b', name: '2'}, 
           {_id: 'c', name: '3'}];
const B = ['2', '3'];
const C = [];
A.forEach((item) => {
    if(B.filter(x=>x == item.name).length > 0) {
        C.push(item)
    }    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope I have been helpful

```js
const arrA = [{ _id: 'a', name: '1' }, { _id: 'b', name: '2' }, { _id: 'c', name: '3' }];
const arrB = ['2', '3'];
var arrC = [];

arrB.forEach(element => {
    arrA.forEach(element2 => {
        if (element === element2.name) {
            arrC.push(element2)
        } 
    });
});

console.log(arrC);
```